# Google Grid Gallery Safari modal scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, gallery

I'm redesigning a website and came across this Blueprint from codrops: https://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/03/21/google-grid-gallery/. I liked how it looked and thought it would really help my gallery stand out.

I have been able to integrate the gallery script and WordPress, but I am having a small issue with the modal window. When you click on a thumbnail, the modal window opens...you see the title, a picture, and some text. The height of the window is set, but some of the text doesn't fit within the window, so I decided to enable scrolling.

Scrolling works in Internet Explorer, Firefox, and Google Chrome. Unfortunately, the scrolling seems to be disabled or locked in Safari and I'm not sure what's causing the issue. I'm pretty sure it has something to with the css, but after removing pieces of code here and there I have not been able to find the culprit.

My work in progress is at: http://www.joshrodg.com/test/

The code looks like:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="grid-gallery" class="grid-gallery">
        <section class="grid-wrap">
            <ul class="grid">
                <li class="grid-sizer"></li><!-- for Masonry column width -->
                <li>
                    <figure>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h3>Alan Zinter</h3>
                            <a href="http://joshrodg.com/test/wp-content/uploads/img_043.jpg" rel="lightbox[80]"></a>
                            <p>
                                Inducted in 2009<br>
                                Four year letterman for Hanks High School<br>
                                All District and All City Honoree<br>
                                El Paso High School Player
                            </p>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section><!-- // grid-wrap -->
        <section class="slideshow">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <figure>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h3>Alan Zinter</h3>
                            <a href="http://joshrodg.com/test/wp-content/uploads/img_043.jpg" rel="lightbox[80]"></a>
                            <p>
                                Inducted in 2009<br>
                                Four year letterman for Hanks High School<br>
                                All District and All City Honoree<br>
                                El Paso High School Player of the Year in 1986 as a senior<br>
                                Had a .505 batting average<br>
                                Led the state in home runs with 15<br>
                                Led the state in runs batted in with 51<br>
                                Earned baseball scholarship from the University of Arizona<br>
                                As a freshman, he led the team with 7 triples in 1987<br>
                                Played in Alaska Collegiate League and led his team the Mat Su Miners to win the 1987 NBC World Series in Wichita Kansas<br>
                                His sophomore year at Arizona, he led the team in hits with 79 and led the Wildcats in runs batted in with 55<br>
                                Following his sophomore year he played in the Cape Cod League for the Harwich Mariners<br>
                                Played with Team USA in Taiwan – – 1988<br>
                                Led Team USA with a .412 batting average and helped lead them to a Silver Medal with a 6-1 record<br>
                                His junior year he tied the Arizona Wildcats team record with 18 home runs and led the team in runs batted in with 81 RBI and had a .352 batting average<br>
                                Named to the NCAA, Baseball America, The Sporting News and ABCA All American teams<br>
                                Named Pac 10 Conference “Co Player of the Year” with teammate pitcher Scott Erickson<br>
                                Finalist for 1989 Golden Spikes Award<br>
                                Led University of Arizona in hitting categories each of his three years playing in 162 games with 211 hits, 29 home runs, 357 total bases, 35 doubles, 12 triples,                                         172 RBI’s with a .336 batting average<br>
                                Chosen in the First Round, 24th overall selection by the New York Mets in the 1989 Professional Draft<br>
                                Played 19 seasons of professional baseball (1989-2007) with the Mets, Tigers, Red Sox, Mariners, Cubs, Diamondbacks, Astros and in Japan<br>
                                Named to All Star teams for Florida State League (1990) and Pacific Coast League (1997 and 1998)<br>
                                In his 19 seasons, he had 1,562 hits, 276 home runs, 1,013 runs batted in and a .257 batting average<br>
                                Made his major league debut in Milwaukee on June 18, 2002 against the Brewers while playing for the Houston Astros<br>
                                First Major League hit was a home run for the Astros against the Cincinnati Reds in 2002<br>
                                Played in Major Leagues for Astros and Arizona Diamondbacks organizations<br>
                                Hitting Coach for Arizona Diamondbacks minor league teams at Missoula and Visalia in 2008 and 2009
                            </p>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <nav>
                <span class="icon nav-prev"></span>
                <span class="icon nav-next"></span>
                <span class="icon nav-close"></span>
            </nav>
        </section><!-- // slideshow -->
    </div><!-- // grid-gallery -->
</div>
```

The css looks like:

```
 /* Made with http://icomoon.io/app */

/* General style */
.grid-gallery ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.grid-gallery figure {
    margin: 0;
}

.grid-gallery figure img {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.grid-gallery figcaption h3 {
    color: #cc0000;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 25px;
    padding: 0 0 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.grid-gallery figcaption p {
    color: #084872;
    margin: 0;
}

/* Grid style */
.grid-wrap {
    max-width: 69em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 1em 1.875em;
}

.grid {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.grid li {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.grid figure {
    padding: 15px;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

.grid li:hover figure {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.grid figcaption {
    background: #e4e4e4;
    padding: 25px;
}

/* Slideshow style */
.slideshow {
    position: fixed;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 500;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
    perspective: 1000px;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s, visibility 0s 0.5s;
    transition: opacity 0.5s, visibility 0s 0.5s;
}

.slideshow-open .slideshow {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.slideshow ul {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,150px);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,150px);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.slideshow ul.animatable li {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.slideshow-open .slideshow ul {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.slideshow li {
    width: 660px;
    height: 560px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -280px 0 0 -330px;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.slideshow li.show {
    visibility: visible;
}

.slideshow li:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.slideshow li.current:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
}

.slideshow figure {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    border: 25px solid #fff;
    overflow: auto;
}

.slideshow li figure img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 300px;
}

.slideshow figcaption {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.slideshow figcaption h3 {
    color: #dd0000;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 0 0 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.slideshow figcaption p {
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Navigation */
.slideshow nav span {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    color: #59656c;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3%;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 2.2em;
}

.slideshow nav span.nav-prev,
.slideshow nav span.nav-next {
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.slideshow nav span.nav-next {
    right: 0;
}

.slideshow nav span.nav-close {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    color: #31373a;
}

.icon:before,
.icon:after {
    font-family: "Ionicons";
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

span.nav-prev:before {
    content: "\f124";
}

span.nav-next:before  {
    content: "\f125";
}

span.nav-close:before {
    content: "\f2d7";
}

/* Info on arrow key navigation */
.info-keys {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 60px;
    font-size: 8px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-align: center;
}

.info-keys:before,
.info-keys:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 14px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.info-keys:before {
    left: 10px;
    content: "\e603";
}

.info-keys:after {
    right: 10px;
    content: "\e604";
}

/* Example media queries (reduce number of columns and change slideshow layout) */

@media screen and (max-width: 60em) {
    /* responsive columns; see "Element sizing" on http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html */
    .grid li {
        width: 33.3%;
    }
    .slideshow li {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .slideshow li figure img {
        width: auto;
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    .slideshow nav span,
    .slideshow nav span.nav-close {
        font-size: 1.8em;
        padding: 0.3em;
    }
    .info-keys {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 35em) {
    .grid li {
        width: 50%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 24em) {
    .grid li {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up choosing to remove the Lightbox all together and just stick with loading the content on a regular page, which is working with scrollbars :-)